# Why can MSBuild not find the CheckRemoteFx45 task?

Tags: .net, build, msbuild, msdeploy, webdeploy

I'm trying to deploy to IIS using MSBuild. In particular I'm running the following MSBuild command:

`msbuild C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\49ca329357fce9a6\trunk\Web\Web.csproj /P:Configuration=Debug /P:DeployOnBuild=True /P:DeployTarget=MSDeployPublish /P:MsDeployServiceUrl=https://192.168.1.1/MsDeploy.axd /P:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True /P:MSDeployPublishMethod=WMSvc /P:CreatePackageOnPublish=True /P:UserName=user /P:Password=password /P:DeployIisAppPath=web`

It builds the project and then I get the following error:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(4715,7): error MSB4062: The "CheckRemoteFx45" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll. Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask. [C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\49ca329357fce9a6\trunk\Web\Web.csproj]`

Is there something I need to install? Note this is not the server with IIS on it, this is the server that has Teamcity on it.

Comment: FYI we found, and fixed, the root cause. This shouldn't be happening any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, I'm not sure why you are getting that error.

To workaround it you can set the property `_Enable45Check` to false and the check should be avoided.

FYI we removed the check all together so if you update to the latest you should be good as well.

Comment: Update to a more recent version of msbuild or visual studio? Also is that just a property that i can set like `/P:_Enable45Check=false` in the command line?

Comment: Visual Studio, and yes that's how to pass it in.

Comment: The flag worked (and I'm just updating visual studio... I thought I already had Update 1 on there but apparently not). Thanks.

Comment: @SayedIbrahimHashimi In the interest of clarity, by "update to the latest", you are referring to the [Azure SDK](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/downloads/archive-net-downloads/)?

Comment: @RichardSzalay yes that is correct. But I've fixed the issue on the server side so you should not be seeing this anymore.

Comment: @PiersKarsenbarg how do you set the /P:_Enable45Check=false flag?  I'm not able to do so using the VS command prompt, It gives me: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.  Thanks.

Comment: Hello @SayedIbrahimHashimi, please tell the detail, I got same error